# Filtering depending upon the column values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet FC, with this sheet, I have column R, S and T filled. 
I would prefer to have a code, which checks if R contains "invalid" and if S and t are filled, then it should filter complete row.

I know we can use isblank function to check whether the cell is blank or not, 
but I am struck how I can use a filter function with these condition .Any help will be helpful for me. I am struck how I can proceed with a vba code. Apologize me for not having a code.

Comment: Start by recording a macro and see what it does. Then try to adjust it for your needs. When you hit the next hurdle, come here and ask a specific question, showing what you've done so far to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cel As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")   'change Sheet3 to your data sheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row in Column R

        For Each cel In .Range("R5:R" & lastRow)    'loop through each cell in range R5 to lase cell in Column R
            If cel.Value = "invalid" And Not IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(cel.Offset(0, 2)) Then
                cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide row if condition is satisfied
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

***EDIT :***

To unhide rows.

```
Sub UnhideRows()
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I completey understand that . This was my  requirement as well. Out of curiosity I asked, is there a way , I can unhide them ?

Comment: @Jenny - I didn't understand what you are asking. Above code hides the row where cell in `Column R` is `invalid` and `Column S, Column T` are not blanks.

Comment: In another sub routine, you may have a single line of code to unhide the rows if they are hidden. ActiveSheet.Rows.Hidden = False

Comment: @sktneer - Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Jenny - You can also use `UNION` to combine all rows to be deleted and then hide them together.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to somehow specify last row:

```
Dim lastRow, i As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow 'specify lastRow variable
    If InStr(1, LCase(Range("R" & i).Value), "invalid") > 0 And Range("S" & i).Value = "" And Range("T" & i).Value = "" Then
        'do work
    End If
Next i
```

In our `If` condition we check three things that you asked.

Comment: but my work is to do filter function; with your code, I could sense that it checks my condition. Could you tell me how I could do filter with this ? After checking my condition, I need to filter the complete row

Comment: So wrap it in a `Function()` statement. Code that you asked is provided...

Comment: What do you mean by "filter entire row"? Should program delete it or what?

Comment: No program should not delete it . It should perform something like autofilter

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my request. How I can perform filter condition with my case .

Comment: Turczyn. Am I clear with my request ? Could you help me to perform this condition ?

Comment: No, you are not. I don't understand your requirements. I provided code that solves problem you mentioned (as I understand it).

Comment: Turczyn; I requested for, I have three columns in sheet to be considered. If my column R contains invalid, it should be filtered ; if the column S and T are filled, then also, it should be filtered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154785/discussion-between-jenny-and-michal-turczyn).

Comment: sformula = "=AND(S5<>""Invalid"",OR(ISBLANK(T5),ISBLANK(U5)))" this is the formula I tried

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Row1 is the header row and your data starts from Row2, in a helper column, place the formula given below.

This formula will return either True or False, then you may filter the helper column with either True or False as per your requirement.

```
=AND(R2="Invalid",S2<>"",T2<>"")
```

In case your header row is different, tweak the formula accordingly.

Comment: I don't want a formula. I would like to have In VBA. The header of my row is 4 . Could you provide me vba script ?

Comment: I would like to perform it automatically. Also, with the helper column,. I don't prefer using a autofilter function. Something like hiding the rows ?

Comment: with Autofilter , I am not able to work the same code with other system

Answer (score 1):

```
sub myfiltering()
'maybe first row always 4
firstrow=4

'last, maybe R column alaways have any entered info, so let us see what is the last
lastrow=cells(65000,18).end(xlup).row

'go ahead
for myrow=firstrow to lastrow
  if cells(myrow,18)="Invalid" and cells(myrow,19)="" and cells(myrow,20)="" then

    Rows(myrow).EntireRow.Hidden = True

  else

    Rows(myrow).EntireRow.Hidden = false

  end if

next myrow

msgbox "Filter completed"
end sub
```

hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need the vba code for this problem?

Its more simple if you add a new column with if & and formula, and autofiltering within the added col.
The formula may be similar like this in the U2 cell.

```
=if(and(R2="invalid";S2="";T2="");"x";"")
```

Also set autofilter to x. :)

Comment: I am learning VBA. and I am struck with this case. That's why I asked for VBA